# Issue removing item from list

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a to do list where I remove items and change their status to completed. When I click the checkbox of an item it only deletes the first item, and when I attempt to change the status of the item to completed it says this item does not exist. Therefore, I'm assuming it's an issue with the index of the item I'm passing into the remove function. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

**These are the todo objects:**

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    {
      text: "Learn about React",
      isCompleted: true
    },
    {
      text: "Meet friend for lunch",
      isCompleted: false
    },
    {
      text: "Wash Dishes",
      isCompleted: false
    }
  ]);
```

**This is what's called when I remove the item**

```
const removeTodo = index => {
    const checkTodos = [...todos];         //The list is copied and isCompleted is changed to true
    checkTodos[index].isCompleted = true;  //This line results in: 
    setTodos(checkTodos);                  //Cannot set property 'isCompleted' of undefined

    const newTodos = [...todos];           //Here is where I remove from the list
    newTodos.splice(index, 1);             //I remove the specific index but it deletes only the first 
    setTodos(newTodos);                    //item no matter where I click
  };
```

**This is how I call the remove function**

```
<div style = {{paddingTop: 40}}>
  <List>
    {todos.map((value) => {
      return(
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Checkbox
              edge="start"
              checked={value.isCompleted}
              onChange={removeTodo}         //Remove function is called here 
              tabIndex={-1}
              disableRipple
            />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText disableTypography style={{fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 35}} primary={value.text}/>
        </ListItem>
      );
    })}
  </List>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, you aren't actually passing an index to the `removeTodo` function, so how will it know which one you're referring to? Also, if you're dealing with a dynamic list (adding/removing elements) you can't use index as the identifier. They need something unique

Comment: @pilchard: shouldn't that be `onChange={() => removeTodo(index)}`?

Comment: yes, but too late to edit it, alas.

Comment: I agree with Jayce444 that you should be using a unique id of some sort to reference todos, but to get what you have working try passing index from map to onChange... `{todos.map((value, index) => { ... <Checkbox onChange={() => removeTodo(index)}>...}`

Comment: I will change it to a unique identifier based on your advice, for now I'm going to try and get the basics working. I tried changing it to onChange={() => removeTodo(index)} but it says index doesn't exist so I tried onChange={() => removeTodo(value)} and it says Cannot set property 'isCompleted' of undefined

Comment: did you add index to the passed arguments from `map()`? `{todos.map((value, index) =>`

Comment: Thank you @pilchard this edit fixed my issue. I'm a little confused regarding the syntax, wasn't value already passing the index.

Comment: Glad it helped. The `map()` function is able to pass three arguments to the callback: the current value (a todo Object in your case), the index of the value in the array, and the entire array. Docs here: [MDN Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @pilchard I see now that it was an optional parameter, thanks so much everything's working perfectly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react if you use **Map** you should give a key to your children so that it could identify all uniquely. Then call the **removeTodo** with the index to remove it properly.

```
<div style = {{paddingTop: 40}}>
  <List>
    {todos.map((value, index) => {
      return(
        <ListItem key={value}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Checkbox
              edge="start"
              checked={value.isCompleted}
              onChange={() => removeTodo(index)}          
              tabIndex={-1}
              disableRipple
            />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText disableTypography style={{fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 35}} primary={value.text}/>
        </ListItem>
      );
    })}
  </List>
</div>
```